# Php Ajax response in window.open

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to `echo` the following content from a controller in an AJAX response:

```
$url = url('/expert-profile-view')."/".$request->ticket_id."/".$key->user_id;
$url = "<a onclick='window.open('$url','mywindow','width=1100,height=500');' class='circle-button btn btn-xs' ><i class='im-billing'></i>View Profile</a>";
echo $url;
```

However I'm not getting the proper response. It always remove slashes and adds extra quotes as following:

```
<a onclick="window.open(" http:="" localhost="" bte="" expert-profile-view="" 54="" 2','mywindow','width="1100,height=500');'" class="circle-button btn btn-xs"><i class="im-billing"></i>View Profile</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the quotes within the JS you're embedding in the HTML string. You need to escape the quotes wrapping the attribute values:

```
$url = "<a onclick=\"window.open('$url', 'mywindow', 'width=1100,height=500');\" class=\"circle-button btn btn-xs\"><i class=\"im-billing\"></i>View Profile</a>";
```

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped